# I want to get the length of number (integer/float) entered by the user in the input prompt

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that takes a number as an argument and returns the length of digits it has. The number can be negative and if user input float like **123.4567** the function will return 8 not 3.
Only float and integers are allowed. But when I provide an integer/float number in the `prompt` and click on the button, it shows me nothing.

**For example:**

if user inputs 5367, output will be 4 and if user inputs 34.567, output will be 5

**Here is the JavaScript Code:**

```
var x = prompt('enter your digit: ')
function numDigits(x) {
  x !== Number.isInt() ? 'only float & integer numbers are allowed' :
  x = Number(String(x).replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
  var b = (Math.log10((x ^ (x >> 31)) - (x >> 31)) | 0) * Math.LOG10E + 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = b;
}
```

[here is JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48tyjquh/)

Comment: `x !== Number.isInt()` this doesn't make any sense at all. You probably meant just `Number.isInteger(x)`? Then again, the text says floats are allowed, which again doesn't add up.

Comment: I write this line for checking if the input is only float and integer number

Comment: `typeof x === "number"` is an easier check then.

Comment: or use `isNaN(x) === false`

Comment: but it will take '.' and will it not give error if I use negative number? @axiac

Comment: @axiac Yes and that would be consistent with the question.  `"123.4567" the function will return 8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main issue of your code is, you did not pass parameter of the function `numDigits()` when you click on the button but you received `x` in the parameter of that function. As you did not pass any parameter but you receive it into the function so it gets the value of `undefined` for `x` and outer `x` is not used inside of that function.

**Here is your code:**

```
<button onclick = "numDigits()"> Click Here </button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Please try this code:

```
var x = prompt('enter your digit: ')

function numDigits() {
  if(isNaN(x)){
    alert('only numbers are allowed');
    return;
  }

    var len = 0;
  len = x.indexOf('.') > -1? x.toString().length - 1 : x.toString().length;

  alert("The length of your number is " + len);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method to get would be as follows:

```js
function getDigitsCount(n) {
    if (isNaN(n)) 
        return "Expected a number..";
    return `${n * 1}`.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace('-', '').length;
    // Multiply number with 1 so that the scientific numbers are 
    // converted to decimal form
}
```

Modify your code to something like:

```
<button onclick = "onClick()"> Click Here </button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var x = prompt('enter your digit: ')
  function getDigitsCount(n) {
      if (isNaN(n)) 
          return "Expected a number..";
      return `${n * 1}`.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace('-', '').length;
  }

  function onClick() {
    demo.innerHTML = getDigitsCount(x);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have used your code on jsfiddle but still no output when clicking 'click here'

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: Check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/p6mxqnb4/ . I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This works for small positive integers, and nothing more. Failure cases: -1, 0.1, 1e100, Infinity, ...

Comment: nice it's working but not properly if I input 12e3 => 4 (expected 'Expected a number..'), 12er=> no output (expected 'Expected a number..'), 12.34=> 5 (expected '4')

Comment: Ok. Now, the specifications are clear. But 1 doubt. How is `12e3` not a number?

Comment: so user can use e for exponent? @VighneshRaut

Comment: Yea. 'e' is used to multiply the number with powers of 10. For eg. `1234e20` means `1234 * (10^20)`

Comment: I understand but how this will give output I mean how many digits will it show the user?

Comment: That, again, depends on your specification. In the above example, `12e4` will output `4` where in fact `12e4` evaluates to `120000` and its digit-count is `6`. So, we need to decide what output we want to display and then, code accordingly.

Comment: I know that thanks a lot for your code everything is working fine now :) I just want 12e4 which means 120000 will output 6 can you edit the code for last time? Thanks again @VighneshRaut

Comment: For that, you can just multiply the number with 1 to force the evaluation.